# Most efficient way to search a map of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a map of arrays of numbers in JavaScript.  My goal is to get the key of the value that contains a certain number.  I'm also open to a different data structure that might be more efficient.

```
let bookCategory = {
    "fantasy": [10064, 10066, 10071],
    "scifi": [10060, 10037, 10061],
    "history": [10001, 10003, 10004, 10005],
    "biography": [10032, 10006, 10002, 10028, 10009, 10030, 100031],
    "educational": [10025]
};
```

Each number will only ever appear once, but each array can contain close to a hundred numbers and it may grow substantially from there.  The arrays could be immutable as my data is static.

Right now I have this, but it doesn't seem terribly efficient.

```
let category;
let keys = _.keys(categories);
let theNumber = 10032;

for(let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    if(_.includes(categories[keys[j]], theNumber)) {
        category = keys[j];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what should be the output for `10001` and `300` be?

Comment: @SalvadorDali those numbers aren't in any of the arrays so category would remain `undefined`.

Comment: If those are different - create a map from the value to the category.

Comment: could a number be in more than one category?

Comment: @NinaScholz Nope.  Each number only appears a single time, if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lodash](http://lodash.com) library has a lot of useful functions. Using it, you have the following options:

**1. Binary search**

Create a new structure with sorted array of numbers. When looking for a number, apply a binary search.
[_.sortedIndexOf()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortedIndexOf) method uses binary search in an array.

```
var bookCategory = {
 "fantasy": [10064, 10066, 10071],
 "scifi": [10060, 10037, 10061],
 "history": [10001, 10003, 10004, 10005],
 "biography": [10032, 10006, 10002, 10028, 10009, 10030, 100031],
 "educational": [10025]
};

var binaryMap = _.mapValues(bookCategory, function(category) {
  return category.sort(function(num1, num2) { 
    return num1 - num2; 
  });
});

//then search using binary algorithm    
var number = 10032;
var keyForNumber = _.findKey(binaryMap, function(numbers) {
  return _.sortedIndexOf(numbers, number) !== -1;
});

keyForNumber // prints "biography"
```

Check the working [demo](http://jsbin.com/wajisecoyi/1/edit?js,console).

**2. Create a map object**

Because the numbers will appear only once, it's easy to create a big hash object, where the key is the number and value is the category. It requires a bit more memory because copies the categories string, but it works quite fast.
This solution doesn't require lodash.

```
var bookCategory = {
 "fantasy": [10064, 10066, 10071],
 "scifi": [10060, 10037, 10061],
 "history": [10001, 10003, 10004, 10005],
 "biography": [10032, 10006, 10002, 10028, 10009, 10030, 100031],
 "educational": [10025]
};

var map = _.reduce(bookCategory, function(result, numbers, key) {
  _.each(numbers, function(number) {
    result[number] = key;
  });
  return result;
}, {});

// or alternative without lodash
var mapAlternative = Object.keys(bookCategory).reduce(function(result, key) {
  bookCategory[key].forEach(function(number) {
    result[number] = key;
  });
  return result;
}, {});


var number = 10003;
map[number]; // prints "history"
```

Check the working [demo](http://jsbin.com/yatukarevo/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: Lodash is not necessary for the second proposition.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many `what-ifs` to answer that question, the biggest one being: How often is the data going to be `updated` vs `read`.

If it is going to be `read` much more often, then iterate through the `bookCategory` first and create a sparse array/object that links the numbers back to the category.

(I'll go for object here):

```
// Generate this programatticly, of course.
bookCategoryLinkback = {
    10064: "fantasy",
    10066: "fantasy",
    10071: "fantasy"
};
```

Comment: My arrays are completely static.  If I was using something like `Immutable` I could freeze them completely.   No updates at all.

Comment: Then I'd use a loop, similar to what you have, and just create a new backreference object like I show above.

Answer (score 0):

sort the array and use binary search. You can use lodash lib to do it easily.

Comment: Wouldn't the sorting take longer than simply iterating through them looking for the answer?  Or is sort a faster operation than I'm thinking.

Comment: @diplosaurus we have no idea what you're thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a hashtable for the numbers.

```js
var bookCategory = {
        "fantasy": [10064, 10066, 10071],
        "scifi": [10060, 10037, 10061],
        "history": [10001, 10003, 10004, 10005],
        "biography": [10032, 10006, 10002, 10028, 10009, 10030, 100031],
        "educational": [10025]
    },
    numbers = function (data) {
        var r = Object.create(null);
        Object.keys(data).forEach(k => data[k].forEach(a => r[a] = k));
        return r;
    }(bookCategory)

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(numbers, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```